# Перебор всех элементов вектора пар, c++

Tags: c++, vector

У меня есть вектор пар
`vector<pair<int, int>> direct = { {2, 1}, {1, 2}, {-2, 1}, {-1, 2}, {-2, -1}, {-1, -2}, {2, -1}, {1, -2} };`

как мне пройтись по элементам этого вектора с помощью такой конструкции:

```
for (int d_x, int d_y : direct) {
    //блок кода
}
```

т.е. d_x и d_y - это соответственно первый и второй элемент пары.
я знаю, что можно просто использовать .fisrt и .second, но можно сделать так?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот так (С++17):

```
for (auto [d_x,d_y] : direct) {
    //блок кода
}
```

Comment: Если я так ввожу, пишет, что идентификатор d_x не определен

Comment: в ответе не хватает предупреждения о c++17…

Comment: @Fat-Zer Да, как-то и не подумал, что где-то его еще нет... (Хотя должен был: сегодня на работе столкнулся сразу с двумя машинами с XP :))